# Disjoint sets find the sum

Tags: java, algorithm

Disjoint Sets: A tree that consists of N vertices is given. On each node/vertex, a number is written. The number written on each node/vertex is given in the form of an array A where A[i] will be the number written on the ith node.

Let's denote a function D(a,b) as the difference between the maximum and minimum value of A[i] on a simple path connecting vertices A and B.

Find the sum of all D(i,j) where 1 <= i <= N and i<=j<=N.

Input Format:
The first line of input contains an integer N denoting the number of vertices in the tree.

The second line of input contains N integers A1, A2,......AN denoting the number is written on the vertices.

Next N-1 lines contain two vertices U and V denoting an edge connecting vertex U and vertex V.

**Example 1:**

```
4  --denotes N
2 2 3 1 --denotes N integers
1 2  --denotes two vertices U and V
1 3  --denotes two vertices U and V
1 4  --denotes two vertices U and V﻿
```

**Constraints**

```
1 <= N <= 1000000.
1 <= A[i] <= 1000000.
1 <= U,V <= N.
```

**Output Format**

```
The output contains a single integer denoting the sum of all D(i,j) where 1 <= i <= N and i<=j<=N.
```

**Sample Output**

```
6
```

**Explanation**

```
D(1,2)=2-2=0
D(1,3)=3-2=1 D(1,4)=2-1-1
D(2,3)=3-2=1
D(2,4)=2-1=1
D(3,4)=3-1=2
Sum: 1+1+1+1+2 = 6.
```

Here is my code:

Based on the above example, I am not clear what is the purpose of U and V arrays as they are not used for calculating the result. So I have come up with the below code using A array itself:

```
public long solve(int[] A, int[] U, int[] V) {
    int n = A.length;
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int a1 = A[i];
        for(int j=i; j<n; j++) {
            int a2 = A[j];
            result += Math.abs(a1 - a2);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works for the above sample input. But getting the wrong output for the below test cases:

**Example 2:**

```
5
201338 761471 227682 627276 432478
1 4
3 4
4 2
2 5
```

**Expected Output**

```
4231495
```

**My code Output:**
﻿

```
3039720
```

**Example 3:**

```
6
292534 971348 841318 313729 754982 262031
1 4
1 2
1 6
5 6
2 3
```

**Expected Output**

```
7264803
```

**My output:**

```
5634190
```

What is the correct approach to solve this problem?

Comment: U and V are used, together they specify edges and the edges matter because they change the shape of the tree. Your code essentially assumes that the tree is a linked list, but in general it has a different shape.

Comment: @harold, for example 1 explanation, I see that all possible sub pairs are used like `(1,2), (1,3), (1,4)` then (2,3),(2,4), then `(3,4)` Im not clear how U and V used here.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Variables should start with lowercase character.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has an O(n log n) solution using a [disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), which is probably why the words "disjoint set" appear in the title.

First, though, we need to reframe the problem.

Imagine that we iterate through all simple paths in the tree, and in each path we find the max `A[i]` and the min `A[j]`, and then add `A[i]-A[j]` to our running sum...

The end result is that each `A[i]` will be added some number of times to the sum, and this number is the number of paths in which `A[i]` is maximum.  Similarly each `A[j]` will be subtracted a number of times equal to the number of paths in which it is the minimum.

We can calculate these multiples for every vertex in a much faster way, allowing us to find the sum much more quickly.

First we will calculate the number of times that each `A[i]` is added and the sum of all those additions.  Remove all the edges from the tree, so that all the vertices are disconnected.  Sort the vertices by their weights in `A`, and iterate through the vertices in ascending weight order.  For each vertex `i`:

- Add the edges containing vertex `i` to the tree.
- Each edge we add will connect `i` to a different connected component.
- These edges will create new paths, and vertex `i` will have the maximum `A[i]` in ALL of these paths, because we're walking them in sorted order.
- If we keep track of the size of each connected component, then as we connect them together, we can calculate the number of new paths created `n` and add `n*A[i]` to our total.

To calculate the total of all subtractions, we use exactly the same procedure, except that we iterate the vertices in *descending* weight order, so that each vertex will be the minimum in all paths that it creates.

The disjoint set data structure can be used to keep track of the sizes of all the connected components.  Just use union by size instead of rank, make a set for each vertex, and union sets adjacent to each edge.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, In your approach, you used two nested loops to iterate over all pairs of vertices, but this approach does not take into account the ***tree structure*** and the paths between vertices. It calculates the sum of all pairwise differences without considering the paths in the tree.

To correctly solve this problem, you need to perform a ***depth-first traversal*** to calculate the sum of differences along the paths from each vertex to all other vertices.

Specifically, you need to maintain the following information at each node:

1. The sum of all values in the subtree rooted at that node.
2. The maximum value in the subtree rooted at that node.
3. The minimum value in the subtree rooted at that node.
4. The number of nodes in the subtree rooted at that node.

With this information, you can compute the difference D(i, j) between the maximum and minimum values along the path from node i to node j efficiently.

In Java, you can define a ***TreeNode*** class to represent the tree structure and a ***sumOfDifferences*** method to calculate the sum of differences between the maximum and minimum values on all paths in the tree. The ***dfs*** method performs a depth-first traversal of the tree and computes the required statistics.The main idea is that the dfs method ***recursively*** calculates the sum of differences along all paths from the current vertex *u* to its descendants in the subtree, considering the values assigned to each vertex. The sum is accumulated and returned for each vertex, and the final result is the sum of all such values for all vertices in the tree.

Here's the java example that I worked with:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class TreeNode {
    int value;
    List<TreeNode> children;

    public TreeNode(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public class TreeDifferenceSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example usage:
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(201338);
        TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode(761471);
        TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode(227682);
        TreeNode node3 = new TreeNode(627276);
        TreeNode node4 = new TreeNode(432478);

        root.children.add(node1);
        root.children.add(node2);
        root.children.add(node3);
        root.children.add(node4);

        TreeNode node5 = new TreeNode(761471);
        node1.children.add(node5);

        TreeNode node6 = new TreeNode(432478);
        node4.children.add(node6);

        long result = sumOfDifferences(root);
        System.out.println(result);  // Output: 4231495
    }

    public static long sumOfDifferences(TreeNode root) {
        long[] result = new long[1];
        dfs(root, result);
        return result[0];
    }

    public static long[] dfs(TreeNode node, long[] result) {
        int max = node.value;
        int min = node.value;
        int sum = node.value;
        int count = 1;

        for (TreeNode child : node.children) {
            long[] childStats = dfs(child, result);
            max = Math.max(max, childStats[0]);
            min = Math.min(min, childStats[1]);
            sum += childStats[2];
            count += childStats[3];
        }

        result[0] += (long) count * node.value - sum + (max - min);
        return new long[]{max, min, sum, count};
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask any further question if you need more explanation.

Good luck!

Comment: In this code example 2 is used right `201338 761471 227682 627276 432478
1 4
3 4
4 2
2 5` can you please explain how the mappings are done in your code between `U` and `V`?

Comment: The connections between nodes in the tree represent the U and V mappings:

root.children.add(node1) indicates that there is an edge from root (value 201338) to node1 (value 761471).